# Array Split duas vezes Python

Tags: python, array, python-3.x

Preciso pegar `coordenadas cartesianas` e separar elas, de forma que saiba de qual é o par ordenado. Recebo uma `string` onde os pontos vem dessa maneira: `x0,y0 x1,y1 ... xn,yn`
Utilizei um `array split` por espaço primeiro e depois um array por virgulas, o problema é que do jeito que fiz está somente armazenando o `valor do primeiro par ordenado`. Preciso utilizar `while/for` para percorrer todo o array de forma que não importe a quantidade de pontos digitados
Código:

```
pontos=vetor.split(' ')

while(cont<(2*len(pontos))):
    cord.append(0)
    cont=cont+1
cont=0
while(i<len(pontos)):
    p=(pontos[i].split(',')
        while(len(p)>cont):
           cord[cont]=p[cont]
           cord[cont+1]=p[cont+1]
           cord=cord+1
    i=i+1
    p=[]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira mais simplificada seria:

```
vetor = "0,3 4,5 6,7 10,4 0,3 5,3"

coord = [list(map(int,v.split(','))) for v in vetor.split()]

print(coord)
```

```
[[0, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [10, 4], [0, 3], [5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
coordenadas=[]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        coordenadas.append([i,j])

print(coordenadas)
```