# Remover caracteres especificos de uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Minha duvida é o seguinte, tem algum modo de remover a virgula de uma lista? estou utilizando o .strip para retirar os colchetes, porém quando defino a virgula como parâmetro não funciona, tentei o .replace mas acaba dando erro.

```
    with open('reservas.txt', 'w') as doc:
        for k in range(0, len(reserva)):
             doc.write(f'{str(save_temp[k])} {str(save_temp2[k]).strip("][")}\n'
```

A saída no arquivo txt acaba sendo

> 17423215562 0, 2

Preciso que seja removido a vírgula.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Array Split duas vezes Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334186/array-split-duas-vezes-python)

Comment: Poderia informar os valores e significado de `reserva` e `save_temp`?

Answer (score 1):

Existem formas de remover caracteres de listas, porem não é seu caso uma vez que esta criado uma [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string#module-string) ao usar a função `write(string)` para [escrever no documento](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Sendo assim porque simplesmente não usa `f'{str(save_temp[k])} {str(save_temp2[k]).strip("][")}\n'.replace(',','')`

Answer (score 0):

A função strip remove apenas quando o caractere esta nas pontas. ou seja, o primeiro ou último. no exemplo que você deu, não é o caso.

pode usar a função replace, mas ela remove todas as ocorrências.

Se isso não for um problema, o código serve

```
with open('reservas.txt', 'w') as doc:
    for k in range(0, len(reserva)):
         doc.write(f'{str(save_temp[k])} {str(save_temp2[k]).strip("][").replace(",","")}\n'
```